# How to fail a maven build, if JUnit coverage falls below certain threshold

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, code-coverage

I'm getting the Unit test coverage percentage metric from sonar rest api.

How can I fail the build if it falls below a defined value?

Comment: Maven fails by default if JUnit provider detects a test error.

Comment: It is to fail the build based on JUnit coverage percentage for a project.It is not for the JUnit test  it self.

Comment: What about Cobertura?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`JaCoCo` offers that feature.

## JaCoCo with *Configuration rules*

Define JaCoCo plugin using configuration rules `COVEREDRATIO` for`LINE` and `BRANCH` :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>check</id>
      <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <rules>
          <rule>
            <element>CLASS</element>
            <limits>
              <limit>
                <counter>LINE</counter>
                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                <minimum>0.80</minimum>
              </limit>
              <limit>
                <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                <minimum>0.80</minimum>
              </limit>
            </limits>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>com.xyz.ClassToExclude</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

## Various options

The supported `counter` options are:

- LINE
- BRANCH
- INSTRUCTION
- COMPLEXITY
- METHOD
- CLASS

I believe `INSTRUCTION` would allow you to make a general check (verify that the whole project has at least 0.80 of coverage for instance).

[Example with INSTRUCTION - overall instruction coverage of 80%](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html)

> This example requires an overall instruction coverage of 80% and no
>   class must be missed:
>
> ```
> <rules>
>   <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
>     <element>BUNDLE</element>
>     <limits>
>       <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
>         <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
>         <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
>         <minimum>0.80</minimum>
>       </limit>
>       <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
>         <counter>CLASS</counter>
>         <value>MISSEDCOUNT</value>
>         <maximum>0</maximum>
>       </limit>
>     </limits>
>   </rule>
> </rules>
> ```

## Message on failure

If the coverage isn't as expected, it fails with the following message:

```
[WARNING] Rule violated for class com.sampleapp.SpringConfiguration: lines covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.80
[WARNING] Rule violated for class com.sampleapp.Launcher: lines covered ratio is 0.33, but expected minimum is 0.80
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Exclusions

In the example above, I set `<exclude>com.xyz.ClassToExclude</exclude>`. I think you'll find you need to add many exclusions. Projects usually contain many classes which aren't testable/tested (Spring Configuration, Java beans...). You may be able to use regular expression too.

---

#### sources:

- http://choudhury.com/blog/2014/02/25/enforcing-minimum-code-coverage
- http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html
- http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html

Comment: I've edited, I believe you may also use INSTRUCTION (instead of LINE or BRANCH) to apply a general check on the project (verify that the whole project has at least 0.80 of coverage for instance)

Comment: use `mvn clean verify` to execute it

Comment: hi, sorry to bother you. I use your example in my pom, but an error occurs `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project` I've read more stackoverflows about it, but could not find really an answer. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 0.8.2 or similar versions of jacoco-maven-plugin, please make sure data file is defined, and use the following configuration for the plugin.

```
<execution>
  <id>jacoco-check</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>check</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
    <rules>
      <rule>
        <element>BUNDLE</element>
        <limits>
          <limit>
            <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
            <minimum>0.17</minimum>
          </limit>
        </limits>
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

This code ensures overall coverage of 17%.

Please verify this using

> mvn clean verify

command.

Answer (score 0):

```
Specify the datFile location if it is not under default folder.

<execution>
                <id>check</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <dataFile><path-to-jacoc-ut.exec></dataFile>
                 <rules><rule>
                 <element>CLASS</element>
                 <limits>
                  <limit>
                    <counter>LINE</counter>
                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                    <minimum>0.80</minimum>
                  </limit>
                  <limit>
                    <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                    <minimum>0.80</minimum>
                  </limit>
                </limits>
                <excludes>
                   <exclude>com.xyz.ClassToExclude</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </rule></rules></configuration>
            </execution>
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.