# How to fail a maven build, if JUnit coverage falls below previous coverage?

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage

I've read that we can configure [JaCoCo to fail the maven build if the test code coverage is below a predefined threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891739/how-to-fail-a-maven-build-if-junit-coverage-falls-below-certain-threshold) but how about if we want to fail the build if the test code coverage drops from the **previous test code coverage?**

Comment: I think Jacoco produces all artifacts only on target directory, that can be clean with a simple "mvn clean" command. So Jacoco per se cannot save the value of the previous code coverage metric to be useful to the next run. If you can use a tool like Jenkins or Sonar, then you can configure these rules. Sonar example: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/new-code-period/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Code Coverage API Jenkins plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/code-coverage-api/#plugin-content-rest-api) comes with a [REST API](https://plugins.jenkins.io/code-coverage-api/#plugin-content-rest-api) which includes:

> ### Coverage result of last build:
>
> ```
>  …​/{buildNumber}/coverage/…​/last/result/api/\{json|xml\}?depth={number}
> ```

The idea would be to define a step for storing that value in a variable, and then use said variable in limit configuration:

```xml
<rules>
  <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
    <element>BUNDLE</element>
    <limits>
      <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
        <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
        <minimum>${env.LAST_BULD_COVERAGE}</minimum>
      </limit>
```